# WPF ComboBox DataTemplate dependently on a class

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I am actually creating an WPF application in which I have a combobox binded to list. Source very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344037/conditional-datatemplates-when-binding-to-a-collection).

However, my question is: is it possible to make the same thing while using WPF combobox (using only DataTemplate and XAML)? I mean show label dependently on a class (both dropped and selected item)?

I have tried something like this:

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="VehicleComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=comboboxVehicles}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="452,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
                <TextBlock Text="Car"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Bike}">
                <TextBlock Text="Bike"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
```

Unfortunately VS underline  with message "The namespaces "local" is not defined".

Comment: Does it not work if you do it exactly the same as in the question you quoted? Define `DataTemplate` per type in `ComboBox.Resources`

Comment: Unfortunately VS underline <DataTemplate> with message "The namespaces "local" is not defined"

Comment: Update your question with the code you've tried and you'll be significantly more likely to get help.

Comment: @RomanGda I think you're just missing definition of _local_ namespace in XAML: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Replace.With.Namespace.Where.CarAndBike.Are.Defined"`